# Could not compile Build file

Tags: android, build.gradle

The android project file got deleted mistakenly after I have successfully recovered from Drill Disk and tried to run the project I got an error

```
Build file 'E:\AndroidStudioProjects\side\app\build.gradle' line: 25

Could not compile build file 'E:\AndroidStudioProjects\side\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
build file 'E:\AndroidStudioProjects\side\app\build.gradle': 25: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 25, 
column 2.
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  ^
```

I have tried pasting it from the project the Build.Gradle file from Github still I get the error:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
 }

 allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    center()
  }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

I don't want to pull or create a new instance because I have made the changes in the old file, so if I do it again it will take a lot of time again.

So any expert please help me with what I should do, I have referred to the older post here at Stackoverflow related to this topic But I was unable to get the solution?

Comment: The error is pointing at the last Curly braces of **task clean(type: Delete)**

Comment: It could take some time but you can create new project and copy contents of src folder into it.

Comment: I guess that the best choice I have right now.